# How to reset Linux root and grub passwords?

Tags: linux, password, grub, root

If we forget our Linux root password, we can change it by changing grub's boot options.

But in this case, we also set a grub password and forgot both passwords. How can we recover both?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

Boot from a LiveCD, then mount the `/` harddrive partition. You can now `chroot` into your harddrive and just run `passwd` as root there changing the root `pw`. That's also the way to change to grub password.

Comment: Presently i'm using fedora, Is it possible to use ubuntu  live CD for change password ?

Comment: Yeah, it doesn't really matter what distribution you use.

Comment: @Kumar P: But you should use an 32bit CD for an 32bit system and 64bit CD for 64bit system

Comment: @krissi: Techincally you need 64bit kernel for 64bit system and any kernel for 32bit system. So SysResCD booted with 64-bit kernel (it has only 32-bit userland) can chroot both into 32 and 64 bit systems.

Comment: @Maciej Piechotka: Thats right. But I ran into some trouble in the past with mixing 64bit CD and 32bit. Don't ask my why this happend (maybe some tools read the wrong data from /sys or /proc). Maybe it has changed meanwhile, but I keep my pendrive with both, 32bit and 64bit Linux ;)