# How to change the forgotten root password?

Tags: linux, password, root

I forgot my root password...actually I think I know what it is because it is the same password I have for pretty much everything but in the Terminal in tell me "Sorry, try again." Is there a way to reset the password? If so how?

Comment: possible duplicate of [How to reset Linux root and grub passwords?](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/2262/how-to-reset-linux-root-and-grub-passwords)

Comment: @HaukeLaging That one is harder and specifically says they can't edit the grub boot line, which is the answer posted here

Comment: @MichaelMrozek Right. I have to read more carefully.

Comment: If you are sure you know what the password is, then maybe it got truncated. On an old Linux once I set a 10 character password, which was somehow truncated to the first 8 characters. Just a hint.

Answer (score 11):

1. At the GRUB prompt, press the letter, `e`, to edit.
2. Scroll to the kernel's boot line.
3. Add to the end of the kernel boot parameters this value: `init=/bin/bash`
4. Press `[ENTER]` and then `b` to boot.
5. Remount the root file system in read-write mode: `mount -o remount,rw /`
6. Change the password: `passwd`
7. Reboot: `reboot`

Comment: In my case I just added "single" to the end of kernel line and password change worked without the remount part.

Comment: on Debian Squeeze

Comment: Works on Red Hat 8, with the exception of step 4 which is `Ctrl-X` to boot